# How can I enable chat with everyone in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

When I go into the options, the only two settings are to chat with friends or with no one. How can I enable chat with strangers as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the Roblox site. If your account date of birth is set so that you are 12 years old or less you can only set the chat option to friends or no one.

> Players age 12 and younger can select either Friends or No one, while players age 13 and older have additional options on who can interact with them.

Link: https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313120-Safety-Features-Chat-Privacy-Filtering

Answer (score 0):

That is not an option, if you want to chat with strangers go into games on roblox, or you can just chat with friends when they join the game by PMing them